# Can i pass value received by the java-script in .aspx page to its corresponding .cs file in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a abc.aspx file that is receiving some value using java-script.
i.e.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ccont" Runat="Server">
  <div id="ccont">

       <script type="text/javascript">
           function show(id) {
               alert('id');
           }

       </script>

  <div class="ccont">

  </div>
```

As seen in the code above i can get certain int value say 1,2,3 and so on.But the value is inside the script tag.so my question is:

1. How do i get that value inside the body of the abc.aspx file say inside the div tag? ie anywhere outside the script.
2. How do i pass the value obtained in this abc.aspx file to its abc.axps.cs file

Answer (score 1):

Try using ASP.Net's `HiddenField` control:

```
 <asp:HiddenField ClientIDMode="static" ID="hiddenId" runat="server"/>
```

This will render an invisible input on your page will which hold your value.

Using `jQuery`, you can assign a value to it like this:

```
$(function(){
     var value = $('.ccont').text(); //Get your value somehow
     $('#hiddenId').val(value);
});
```

Once your page is submitted to the server, you will see that the `hiddenId` control will be populated in the page's `OnLoad` handler.

Comment: This is best practice & I use this approach.

Comment: I already have variable value(say id =4) as you can see above in the code.Now i need to pass this value to the .cs file.

Comment: Your code is quite incomplete, I'm trying to provide general guidance. Assign the value to the hidden field as I indicated above: `$('#hiddenId').val(value);` Then when the form is submitted the ASP.Net `HiddenField` will be populated.